# How to Display various files in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, document

I am creating an app where any one can upload any kind of file. I store my files on AWS S3 and while viewing it returns a presigned URL. I use this URL to render images and videos(some formats only), what can I do if I want to display other file formats such as .pdf, .docx, .ppt, etc.

I have tried using google docs as an  but that doesn't work. What possible options do I have, if I want to display various kinds of file formats.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use some specialized React libraries to display these files.

For PDF, you can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-viewer-reactjs.

Comment: Can you give some examples other than the one you mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-file-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer) or something similar.

Comment: I tried that but it added around 3MB to the bundle size...where rest of my bundle was less than 1MB.

Comment: Yes, it is big, though gzipped sized is nearly 900kb.

Comment: Also, most of the features is lazy loaded.

Comment: bhai what do you mean by lazy loaded ? When we use Suspense is React?